# why do php frameworks restrict url characters

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, web, sanitization

I have been searching for why this is true (from codeigniter's default config file).

I want to know why codeigniter acts like this URL sanitization is so important. Not to turn it off, but for the sake of curiosity and to know if its OK to use frameworks that don't have this feature.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allowed URL Characters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This lets you specify with a regular expression which characters are permitted
| within your URLs.  When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed
| characters they will get a warning message.
|
| As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
| as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
|
| Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
|
| DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
|
*/
```

The only reasons I've seen so far have been:

1. hackers are inventive so don't turn it off
2. prevent users from sql injection
3. prevent spoofing to different sites such as http://yoursite.com@hacker.com
4. for URL encoding
5. whitelists are better than blacklists

The first and fifth reasons are basically non-sequiters. Why URLs? If funky URLs don't have security issues, they don't need a blacklist so they don't need this whitelist. If strange URL aren't capable of hacking your site, it would be a wonderful waste of their time to allow their inventive harmless experimentation rather than force them to move onto something actually capable of revealing security holes.

The second reason is flawed for two reasons; firstly this sanitization isn't used on the query string or POST data which is where you'd expect to find most injection attempts. Secondly, this doesn't escape these characters, it denies any request including them. I would be upset as a user if Stack Overflow killed by pageload because my post included an apostrophe.

Reasons three and four simply don't apply. Reason three is that users will think they are going to yoursite.com and actually end up in hacker.com. There is nothing you can do to prevent this, you never receive the request. Similarly, number 4 seems to be led by the misunderstanding that this is generating URLs rather than parsing them. This code is parsing what you can be certain is by this point a valid URL. Codeigniter decodes the URI characters before running this regex.

So those are the answers I have heard and I either don't understand them, or there is a real reason out there I have yet to find, or the code is mostly useless. Any security experts out there who can enlighten me?

Comment: What other characters would you want in a URL? I'd say for SEO purposes, for easy search engine crawling and indexing, readability and more. I do the same in my framework.

Comment: Perhaps for special characters that are in another language? http://www.worldjournal.com/view/full_Anews/22914692/article-G8%E9%87%8D%E9%A0%AD%E6%88%B2-%E6%AD%90%E7%BE%8E%E5%95%9F%E5%8B%95%E8%87%AA%E8%B2%BF%E8%AB%87%E5%88%A4

Comment: @CodeAngry I agree with you there. However that reasoning doesn't mandate that frameworks deliberately kill all requests with ugly URLs.

Comment: @MikeFairhurst *Better safe than sorry.* I like coercing users into proper behavior. **NEVER TRUST THE USER**. It's a mantra for reusable code writers / backenders like me. Trust me, they're doing you a favor. Along with the benefits mentioned above, you get the security bonus. Look into your server access logs and you'll see the amount of hacking attempts that happen daily. They'll get you worried.

Comment: @CodeAngry this is effectively argument 1 of my post.

Comment: For me, I totally disagree with restrictions. Your code should be safe regardless if this feature is enabled or disabled.

Comment: check this page https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet and think how much this filter saved you! don't forget folder traversing if your script had file access and weak security

Comment: @Hawili this is effectively argument 2 of my post, just expanded to be more than SQL. If you have to rely on this filter to escape your data, you are not escaping GET or POST properly. If you are escaping GET or POST properly, you should use that escaping on your URI components at which point early failing provides no security benefit.

Comment: @Hawili I can see a benefit in folder traversing in hindsight though, simply because many developers would not realize that URI encoded slashes can still appear in a URI segment. That _does_ make the URI component data special, compared to GET or POST where devs would more likely be aware that ../ is a possible user input.

Comment: @MikeFairhurst framework is used by people who know, and people who don't, the idea is a "try" to protect the later, but with experience everybody know, no body can save them..

Answer (score 1):

Image. If you wrote a framework that was consistently compromised because of poor coding practices of the coders, then you're not going to have a successful framework. Once the marketing image has been tainted, it's not easy to explain "It's the CODERS fault!". A successful framework isn't compromised and provides by default a base set of security enhancements. Personally, I'd much rather start with a locked down framework and only compromise specific areas than have a framework that's often attacked because of their known vulnerabilities (that's how frameworks end up on known exploits lists)